# Change the font in the header of the document class eskdx

Tags: tables, fontsize

Good afternoon, tell me how to change the font size in the header of the document now looks like this  and it is necessary that it does not go beyond the limits. \footnotsize tried does not help. The preamble is here

```
\documentclass[russian,utf8,floatsection,equationsection,nocolumnsxix]{eskdtext}
% Объявляем документ класса eskdtext (подробнее можно узнать из описания пакета eskdx)
% russian - текст на русском языке, utf8 - кодировка документа UTF-8
% floatsection - нумерация таблиц и рисунков с учётом номера главы, equationsection - то же для формул
\usepackage{longtable} % В документе используем пакет longtable для создания таблиц
\usepackage{graphicx} % Используем графику в документе
 
\usepackage{mathtext} % Русские буквы в формулах
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\No}{\textnumero}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1.25em}}
\makeatother
\ESKDauthor{Яременко.Д.С} % "Разраб." в штампе на листе содержания
 
\ESKDchecker{Степанов А.Ю} % "Пров."  в штампе на листе содержания
 
\ESKDnormContr{Симагин И.М.} % "Н. контр." в штампе на листе содержания
\ESKDapprovedBy{Сидоров С.С.}%  "Увт." в штампе на листе содержания\documentclass[russian,utf8,floatsection,equationsection,nocolumnsxix]{eskdtext}
% Объявляем документ класса eskdtext (подробнее можно узнать из описания пакета eskdx)
% russian - текст на русском языке, utf8 - кодировка документа UTF-8
% floatsection - нумерация таблиц и рисунков с учётом номера главы, equationsection - то же для формул
\usepackage{longtable} % В документе используем пакет longtable для создания таблиц
\usepackage{graphicx} % Используем графику в документе
 
\usepackage{mathtext} % Русские буквы в формулах
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\No}{\textnumero}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1.25em}}
\makeatother
\ESKDauthor{Яременко.Д.С} % "Разраб." в штампе на листе содержания
 
\ESKDchecker{Степанов А.Ю} % "Пров."  в штампе на листе содержания
 
\ESKDnormContr{Симагин И.М.} % "Н. контр." в штампе на листе содержания
\ESKDapprovedBy{Сидоров С.С.}%  "Увт." в штампе на листе содержания
```

[image]

Comment: You do not appear to have posted the code for the table so it is hard to tell you how to make it smaller, please always post a complete small document that shows the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try `14pt or 12pt or 10pt` in `\documentclass[]` and something like `\small{text}` of `\footnotesize{text}` should works

Comment: `\small` and `\footnotesize` do not take an argument